# Is it possible to drag a component from one container to another in react-dnd?

Tags: react-dnd

I have 2 lists of items (same type) and I want to be able to drag and drop items between the containers. For example moving an orange component into the list of yellow components like this image:

[image]

Each of the list items has a prop that indicates it's parent so I feel like I have the necessary info to make this work, like on a move event check if the moving items parent matches the container it's currently moving in. I don't know if it's possible with react-dnd. Has anyone done this? If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: Definitely possible as long as they're in the same DND context, can you provide your code though?